# Is this correct way of using HBase REST API to just parse the response from its URL?

Tags: hadoop

I did not find any example of HBase REST Client to put GET POST request.So instead of this what I am doing is I am just jusing the HBase REST URL ,putting it in my java code and just parsing the response using SAX parser..Is this correct way(bcoz i m not using GET request..i did not find example of using GET post On Hbase REST client)
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples on consuming the REST API, simplest being through "curl":

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/version
```

You can find related documentation here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate.
Response can be consumed as plain text, xml, json or protobuf.

Ruby has gems like [HBase Stargate](https://github.com/greglu/hbase-stargate) and [HBase Ruby](https://github.com/sishen/hbase-ruby) for native support.
How are you trying to consume the REST services? through Java?